# ¿ como puedo ordenar la matriz de objetos de JavaScript por fecha?

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs

hace unos dias vengo pensado en como puedo organizar una matriz de objetos por fecha
ejemplo de la matriz a ordenar:

```
    [
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 2,
    coordenas: '6.320230, -74.455130',
    fecha: '2021-12-15',
    nombre_cliente: 'TOMAS GATILLA',
    hora: '10:33',
    celular: '30030122961',
    Nota: 'OJO NO TIRAR CABLE POR EL AIRE',
    estado: 'INCOMPLETO',
    ip: '12312312',
    plan: '40',
    tv: 'SI',
    tipo_instalacion: 'Instalacion',
    genero: 'Fo',
    id_tecnico: 2,
    foto_ont: '4fabb01f-5c71-4a48-a2eb-6a3c22b1db51.jpg',
    foto_instalacion: '36265218-9911-41a9-bb33-e4508113fb30.jpg',
    foto_sp: 'a6f3d2c8-31b9-4982-be0d-5989527f9b55.jpg',
    foto_cedula: '26baced1-d3bd-47d7-a0bd-acdf4c1afb72.jpg',
    nota_instalacion: '',
    firma: '7f9b289d-9085-4bc9-b29d-a064dd401c22.png',
    evidencias_reprogramacion: '-',
    fecha_fin: '2021-12-14',
    hora_fin: '15:26'
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 18,
    coordenas: '6.372894, -75.671663',
    fecha: '2021-12-13',
    nombre_cliente: 'carlos',
    hora: '11:00',
    celular: '3022835914',
    Nota: 'tener cuidado con los perros',
    estado: 'INCOMPLETO',
    ip: '192.168.201.10',
    plan: '50 megas',
    tv: 'NO',
    tipo_instalacion: 'Instalacion',
    genero: 'Re',
    id_tecnico: 2,
    foto_ont: '',
    foto_instalacion: '',
    foto_sp: '',
    foto_cedula: '',
    nota_instalacion: '',
    firma: '',
    evidencias_reprogramacion: 'porque no estaba el cliente al cual se le realizaria el cambio y los llamos y nos dijo que no podia estar ',
    fecha_fin: '',
    hora_fin: ''
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 19,
    coordenas: '6.372894, -75.671663',
    fecha: '2021-12-18',
    nombre_cliente: 'andres',
    hora: '14:00',
    celular: '3022835914',
    Nota: 'llamar antes de llegar',
    estado: 'INCOMPLETO',
    ip: '192.168.201.10',
    plan: '70 megas',
    tv: 'SI',
    tipo_instalacion: 'Instalacion',
    genero: 'Fo',
    id_tecnico: 2,
    foto_ont: '',
    foto_instalacion: '',
    foto_sp: '',
    foto_cedula: '',
    nota_instalacion: '',
    firma: '',
    evidencias_reprogramacion: '',
    fecha_fin: '',
    hora_fin: ''
  }
]
```

las cuales son bastante grandes entonces necesitaba ver como puedo organizar estas matrices de objeto por fecha ya que la quiero imprimir pero si la imprimo como esta me la imprima por el orden en el que se encuentra y lo que quiero es que lo imprima de forma organizada de la menor fecha a la mayor teniendo en cuenta que pueden ser cualquier fecha y al ser la primera vez que hago esto no tengo la menor idea de hacerlo tienen alguna idea o explicación de como hacerlo detalladamente y e investigado sobre el tema pero no e encontrado una respuesta detallada o que esplique correctamente como hacerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy fácil, puedes usar [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) y usando el constructor [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) para convertir tu `string` a una fecha que JavaScript pueda interpretar como objeto para poder diferenciarlos y saber cuál es mayor o menor

Puedes usar un código algo así

```js
array.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.fecha).getTime() - new Date(b.fecha).getTime());
```

De esta manera ordenarás el array de forma ascendente (de menor a mayor)

```js
const array = [
  {
    id: 2,
    coordenas: '6.320230, -74.455130',
    fecha: '2021-12-15',
    nombre_cliente: 'TOMAS GATILLA',
    hora: '10:33',
    celular: '30030122961',
    Nota: 'OJO NO TIRAR CABLE POR EL AIRE',
    estado: 'INCOMPLETO',
    ip: '12312312',
    plan: '40',
    tv: 'SI',
    tipo_instalacion: 'Instalacion',
    genero: 'Fo',
    id_tecnico: 2,
    foto_ont: '4fabb01f-5c71-4a48-a2eb-6a3c22b1db51.jpg',
    foto_instalacion: '36265218-9911-41a9-bb33-e4508113fb30.jpg',
    foto_sp: 'a6f3d2c8-31b9-4982-be0d-5989527f9b55.jpg',
    foto_cedula: '26baced1-d3bd-47d7-a0bd-acdf4c1afb72.jpg',
    nota_instalacion: '',
    firma: '7f9b289d-9085-4bc9-b29d-a064dd401c22.png',
    evidencias_reprogramacion: '-',
    fecha_fin: '2021-12-14',
    hora_fin: '15:26'
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    coordenas: '6.372894, -75.671663',
    fecha: '2021-12-13',
    nombre_cliente: 'carlos',
    hora: '11:00',
    celular: '3022835914',
    Nota: 'tener cuidado con los perros',
    estado: 'INCOMPLETO',
    ip: '192.168.201.10',
    plan: '50 megas',
    tv: 'NO',
    tipo_instalacion: 'Instalacion',
    genero: 'Re',
    id_tecnico: 2,
    foto_ont: '',
    foto_instalacion: '',
    foto_sp: '',
    foto_cedula: '',
    nota_instalacion: '',
    firma: '',
    evidencias_reprogramacion: 'porque no estaba el cliente al cual se le realizaria el cambio y los llamos y nos dijo que no podia estar ',
    fecha_fin: '',
    hora_fin: ''
  },
  {
    id: 19,
    coordenas: '6.372894, -75.671663',
    fecha: '2021-12-18',
    nombre_cliente: 'andres',
    hora: '14:00',
    celular: '3022835914',
    Nota: 'llamar antes de llegar',
    estado: 'INCOMPLETO',
    ip: '192.168.201.10',
    plan: '70 megas',
    tv: 'SI',
    tipo_instalacion: 'Instalacion',
    genero: 'Fo',
    id_tecnico: 2,
    foto_ont: '',
    foto_instalacion: '',
    foto_sp: '',
    foto_cedula: '',
    nota_instalacion: '',
    firma: '',
    evidencias_reprogramacion: '',
    fecha_fin: '',
    hora_fin: ''
  }
]

const arrayOrdenado = array.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.fecha).getTime() - new Date(b.fecha).getTime());
console.log(arrayOrdenado);
```

Comment: muchas gracias era lo que buscaba has solucionado mi duda feliz dia